# Action Script 3. How to check if current element of array have exact name?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, element

I have an array `myArr` where I keep objects named `item1, item2, item3...` etc.

`trace(myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1]);` this randomly returns `[object Item1]`, `[object Item2]` etc.

I need to make If statement somthing like this:

```
 if (myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1] == Item7) {
 //do something 
}
```

But this doesn't work. I don't get any errors, just nothing happens. How to check current elements name?

Comment: do these objects have properties ? IF so, how many ? Maybe you can refer to this [`compare()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#compare%28%29)-method

Comment: If I use `trace(myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1]);` It returns `[object Item1]` `[object Item2]` etc. Whats about compare() method?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare two objects directly using equality operator (either `==` or `===`). The equality operator looks to the reference address if you are using it on objects.

Each time you create a new object, your variable (or the array) holds the reference address to the newly created object.

Ofc the reference address aren't equal, that's why you are getting false result. You can compare objects in two ways,  *for me, the first one is preferred*.

Here below is an example of an class to create objects with ;

```
public class MyObject {

    public var name:String;
    public var info:String;

    public function MyObject(newName:String, newInfo:String) {
        this.name = newName;
        this.info = newInfo;
    }
}
```

**1. Define a custom compareTo() method,**

Add the next method in your class, here in `MyObject`,

```
public function CompareTo(otherObject:MyObject):Boolean {
    // check properties and compare each properties
    return (this.name == otherObject.name && this.info == otherObject.info); 
}
```

This will only return `true` if the properties are equal. You might use the compare operator with strings. Just expand the above with all properties. If your properties are not public, please use the getters to obtain the property values from other objects. For the current object, `this.` is enough.

Then in your code,

```
if (myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1].compareTo(Item7)) {
    //do something 
}
```

or

```
if (Item7.compareTo(myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1])) {
    //do something 
}
```

both does the same.

**2. use the compare() method from ObjectUtil class**

Please refer first to [this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#compare%28%29) and the explanation (with example) on it. 
Then check the next statement

```
ObjectUtil.compare(myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1], Item7)
```

This will compare both objects using the properties in the `Item` object. Please note that this doesn't work if you have a class as a property. You can add a `depth` option to the above method to do a deep comparison. Still it might be a bit inaccurate if you have polymorph objects.

The result of the above method is an integer, either `-1` or `0` or `1`. Please check the documentation to understand what these numbers represents. You needs the `0` because that says that the compared objects are both equal.

Then your code;

```
if (ObjectUtil.compare(myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1], Item7) == 0) {
    //do something 
}
```

That's how you can start to compare objects correctly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, trace of object with undeclared `toString()` method writes `[object ClassName]` in output. So if I understand your description correctly, you can use this:

```
if (myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1] is Item7) {
    //do something 
}
```

If `Item7` is not a class as it seems, and not a reference to some object stored in your array, and not an instance of such types as `int`, `Number`, `String` etc., then you can declare your custom comparison function to compare this objects, for example:

```
if(Item7.compare(myArr[myRandomNumber2][myRandomNumber1])) {
    // do someting
}
```

And in the class of `Item7`:

```
// ...
public function compare(obj:*):Boolean {
    // your logic here
}
```

In any other case, your code is just incorrect.